# Disabling cache for Magento Block in APC

Tags: magento, caching, apc

I'm using Magento CE v.1.9.0, with APC cache installed. I need to disable cache for block output, but, unfortunately, standart solution isn't working for me:

```
    $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime' => 0,
            'cache_key'      => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId() . '_testcache',
        ));
```

Block still being cached. Any advices, how can I do this, without implementing sick AJAX solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try disabling it via one of your layout xmls.

```
<reference name="block_name">            
  <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by enacting setCacheLifetime on the current block.

So, you need to set lifetime to 0 or null (0 is a more correct way) in the current layout file.

```
<reference name="needed block">
       <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
   </reference>
```

Comment: Subroutines answer helped me, but I think this would work too, thank you.